# If the column value is null, the JSON_ARRAY_APPEND will not update it

Tags: mysql

```
 UPDATE project_sales_registration
 SET buyerInfo = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND (buyerInfo, '$',  
     '[{"page":2,"price": 300,"projectId":"685ak3m65bn"},
     {"page":4,"price":300,"projectId":"685ak3m65bn"},
     {"page":5,"price":300,"projectId":"685ak3m65bn"},
     {"page":8,"price":300,"projectId":"685ak3m65bn"},
     {"page":16,"price":300,"projectId":"685ak3m65bn"},
     {"page":11,"price":300,"projectId":"685ak3m65bn"},
     {"page":11,"price":3000,"projectId":"685ak3m65bn"}]'
   )
 WHERE projectId = '685ak3m65bn';
```

How can I update even when the value is buyerInfo = null
someone please help

Comment: Even when which value is null?

Comment: is buyerInfo column

Comment: Gotta wonder why you're appending a load of data to a JSON column instead of using a separate table.

Comment: Don't let it be null.  Use `ALTER TABLE` to make the default value `"[]"`.  Problem solved.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular, you are exactly correct.  There is a new trend to store JSON in relational database tables.  It is a horrible idea, and I hope it dies a quick death.  Use Mongo if your data must be JSON.  Use relational tables and columns if your data is columnar.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET buyerInfo = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(coalesce(buyerInfo,'[]'), '$'...
```